# Google Analytics User Deletion API - does it actually delete the pageview?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've successfully used the API to delete the clientID and waited about a week for the data to disappear.

However, although the data (clientID) in User Explorer is now gone - the actual pageview still exists in Google Analytics.

So the question is that will the API actually delete the pageview also? Or does it just delete the clientID?

Answer (score 3):

Google Analytics does data pre-aggregation in daily tables for each day, so that report loads faster. With the GDPR and User Data Deletion tool an important milestone that user data is not preserved and cannot be linked to that particular person. Not all of the data which is saved is linked to a clientId and therefore removing data associated with the clientId (and/or userId) may not update the already aggregated tables where user data are counted but not linked to the particular user

From https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3/

> The Google Analytics User Deletion API allows customers to process **deletions of data associated with a given user identifier**